# Keycloak Adapter requires SSL error in AKS

Tags: nginx, spring-security, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I deployed  my spring mvc aplication with tomcat docker image as server in Aks and ingress controller is used for redirection.  My application is secured with Keycloak.
When i try to access my application ,  keycloak console was opening and i can  enter my credentials .
The problem is when I try to login to my app and return from the auth provider (azure)  I get a 403 forbidden and the following message in the application log:

2019-03-07 14:50:45,831 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (default task-9) Adapter requires SSL. Request: http://url?state=c23babe7-6637-48fe-ab6d-1fd93d168e76&session_state=6dea7cb2-27a5-4e9a-9c90-000297d42528&code=304398e5-6fa7-435c-bd4c-a02899d4e412.6dea7cb2-27a5-4e9a-9c90-000297d42528.27a4bd04-e22e-4186-b8c8-cc0895ab429f

My keycloak.json:

{
"realm": "realm name",
"auth-server-url": "https://keycloakurl",
"ssl-required": "all",
"resource": "clientname",
"public-client": true,
"confidential-port": 443,
"principal-attribute": "preferred_username"
}

Seems like Keycloak removing ssl from redirect url in Azure.